# Call javascript after a code behind function has just populated a text box

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page with an asp button that calls a function from code behind in order to do some some stuff involving DLL files. The output of the function is stored in a textbox.
I'd like to call a javascript function just after this textbox is filled up.
None of the below attempts worked. Any tips?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="300px" onchange="javascript:Draw();"></asp:TextBox>

<input type="text" size="20" id="TextBoxHtml" runat="server" onchange="Draw()" /></td>

<input type="text" size="20" id="TextBoxHtml" runat="server" onblur="Draw()" /></td>
```

Summary of the code:

```
//File chart.aspx
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Process" Width="100px" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="300px" ></asp:TextBox>

<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//File chart.aspx.cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff ...
    TextBox2.Text = "200"; 
}

//File: JavaScript.js
function Draw() {
    //Do some stuff ...
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("MainTool_TextBox2").addEventListener('change', function () {
        Draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried handling this on a onload event of the body, or $(document).ready() in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextBox is already filled with content after PostBack, so `onchange` or `onblur` are never triggered client side.

You can call it from code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "callDraw", "Draw()", true);
```

Or check if the value is not empty and call `Draw` like this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').val() !== '') {
            Draw();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be more complete, it is also necessary to have "<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>" just after <body>

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the DOM is loaded, then attach the event listener to the element.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("TextBox2").addEventListener('change', function() {
        draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this error: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference JavaScript.js (107,4) "

Comment: What actually ends up existing as the DOM element? As it appears in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: The cause of the error of the 'addEventListener' was the name of the text box. I think because runat="server", the name changes to "MainTool_TextBox2". Now the problem is not happening, but it has not solved my original issue. By debugging, I see the function "draw();" is not being called...Any idea of the reason?

Comment: With more tests, I see the function "draw();" is not being called just after the text box is filled by the code behind. It is called only when the user changes the text box. But this is not what I want to according to my original question. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds good, then we should be able to just change the event we're listening to. Can you elaborate on what you mean by when the textbox filled? I don't quite understand.

Comment: I added a summary of the code in my question.
Funtion 'Button1_Click' is changing the text box 'TextBox2'. I want this change to trigger javascript function 'Draw()'.